# awk lookup table, blank column replacement

Tags: arrays, awk, lookup

I'm trying to use a lookup table to do a search and replace for two specific columns and keep getting a blank column as output. I've followed the syntax for several examples of lookup tables that I've found on stack, but no joy. Here is a snippet from each of the files.

Sample lookup table -- want to search for instances of column 1 in my data file and replace them with the corresponding value in column 2 (first row is a header):

```
 #xyz   type
 N      400
 C13    401
 13A    402
 13B    402
 13C    402
 C14    405
```

The source file to be substituted has the following format:

```
 1  N      0.293000    2.545000   16.605000     0     2     6    10    14
 2  C13    0.197000    2.816000   15.141000     0     1
 3  13A    1.173000    2.887000   14.676000     0
 4  13B   -0.319000    3.756000   14.937000     0
 5  13C   -0.351000    1.998000   14.678000     0
 6  C14    0.749000    3.776000   17.277000     0     1
```

The corresponding values in column 2 of the lookup table will replace the values in column 6 of my source file (currently all zeroes). Here's the awk one-liner that I thought should work:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==1 { next } FNR==NR { a[$1]=$2; next } $2 in a { $6=a[$1] }1' lookup.txt source.txt
```

But my output essentially deletes the entire entry for column 6:

```
1   N     0.293000  2.545000    16.605000       2   6   10  14
2   C13   0.197000  2.816000    15.141000       1
3   13A   1.173000  2.887000    14.676000   
4   13B  -0.319000  3.756000    14.937000   
5   13C  -0.351000  1.998000    14.678000   
6   C14   0.749000  3.776000    17.277000       1
```

(The sixth column should be 400 to 405. I considered using sed, but I have duplicate values in the source and output columns of my lookup table, so that won't work in this case. What's frustrating is that I had this one-liner working on almost the exact same source file the other week, but now can only get this behavior. I'd love to be able to modify my awk call to do lookups of two different columns simultaneously, but wanted to start simple for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `$6=a[$1]` instead of `$6=a[$2]` in your script.

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{map[$1]=$2; next} {$6=map[$2]} 1' file1 file2
1       N       0.293000        2.545000        16.605000       400     2       6       10      14
2       C13     0.197000        2.816000        15.141000       401     1
3       13A     1.173000        2.887000        14.676000       402
4       13B     -0.319000       3.756000        14.937000       402
5       13C     -0.351000       1.998000        14.678000       402
6       C14     0.749000        3.776000        17.277000       405     1
```

Comment: I knew it was something small I was missing -- thanks so much, Ed! Should have picked up that detail from the handful of other posts of yours I've seen explaining how to use lookup tables.